# Replace a substring in a specific line of a file

Tags: python

I have to find a specific **git_url** in an XML file and replace **commit_num** in the same line.

Xml file content with content as below:

> < git_url="/some_url_name/branchA" commit_num="abc123xyz" user="ASDF"
>   />
>
> < git_url="/some_url_name/branchB" commit_num="xyz123abc" user="LKJH"
>   />

I am trying to follow below:

**First**, find search a git URL in the XML file and get the line number

```
srch_git_url = '/some_url_name/branchB'

with open(sample.xml) as myFile:
    for num, line in enumerate(myFile, 1):
        if srch_git_url in line:
            print 'found at line:', num
```

**Second**, Use this specific line number and then search for a regexp as below and replace with 'commit_num="new_commit_num"'

```
re.search('commit_num="*"')
```

Please help with inputs of more efficient ways to solve this.

Comment: Why are you using Python 2, by the way?

Comment: @AMC Asking regarding the tag ? i have remved the python 2.x tag

Comment: The tag is fine, I’m asking about your use of that version.

Comment: It's because of companies standards and they are yet to update it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `re.sub` function to replace a regex match string with a new string. For rewriting back to the file, you can keep the content of each line including the replaced line using a list and then writing back to the file after you're done reading through the file.

```
import re

srch_git_url = '/some_url_name/branchB'
new_commit_num = 'def567ghi'
with open('sample.xml') as myFile:
    file_lines = myFile.readlines()
    num = 0
    for line in file_lines:
        num += 1
        if srch_git_url in line:
            print 'found at line:', num
            line = re.sub(r'commit_num="(.*)"', 'commit_num="{}"'.format(new_commit_num), line)
            file_lines[num - 1] = line

with open('sample.xml', 'w') as myFile:
    myFile.writelines(file_lines)
```

Comment: @AMC Yeah, the original line `for num, line in enumerate(myFile, 1)` should be fine. I decided to use `.readlines()` in my answer since I didn't want to call `file_lines.append(line)` for every line I iterated through. As for the `file_lines`, I need that to write back to the output file.